# How do I disable the blank console "screensaver" on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: server, command-line, kernel, screensaver

How to disable blank screensaver on Ubuntu Server?

There's no desktop or X, only console (command-line interface).

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The easiest way is to add the parameter `consoleblank=0` to your kernel command-line at boot-time.

- Open `/etc/default/grub` in your favorite editor; you will need to use `sudo` (for `vi`, `nano`, etc.) or `gksudo` (for `gedit`, etc.).
- Then add `consoleblank=0` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=`, parameter.
- e.g. yours may say:

  ```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash consoleblank=0"
  ```

Then run `sudo update-grub`, and reboot.

Comment: Is there a way to do that from Virtualbox? As in passing an option to the kernel command line?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai This answer works for virtualized Ubuntu as well since it boots using _grub_ by default too.

Comment: As in, is there a way to pass it externally from Virtual Box, not from within Ubuntu?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai No, there is no Virtual Box option that will pass on this setting.  You have to edit the file as specified above.

Comment: Look: I don't want to update the `grub` files, just to disable the (Blank) ScreenSaver. I'm resorting, to `setterm -blank 0`, maybe in a file `~/.bashrc`. (See also on [superuser.com an answer to Change Linux console screen blanking behavior](https://superuser.com/a/154388/123800))

Comment: thank you so much this worked great on headless server ubuntu 19.10

Answer (score 23):

Type `setterm -blank 0` on any shell to disable blanking out of tty consoles.

`0` disables blanking, any value greater than 0 is the time in minutes. Default is `10`.

To permanently enable this you can add this line to your `~/.bashrc` config.

A more detailled explaination can be found in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/154388/189848) at superuser.

Comment: This only worked after I ran `TERM=linux` (since I override it in my `.bashrc`).

Comment: Does not unblank the master terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Same situation, the other suggestions seemed a roundabout solution.
Came across the GNU tool `setvesablank on/off` using apropos.
It seems the best fit, trying it out to see if it fits the need.

Comment: In Gnome Terminal on the console it said `Couldn't find a file descriptor referring to the console` - `echo $TERM` returned `xterm-256color - But in "Brightness and Lock" I found a setting for when it blanks the screen and set it to "Never" - but this isn't really on point with the OP since I am in the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

This will "overwrite" whatever is in your current config for "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=", mine was default, so I just use the following One Liner.

```
sudo sed -i 's/\(^GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=\).*/\GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="consoleblank=0"/' /etc/default/grub && sudo update-grub2
```

Comment: I had to escape the '"' character: sed --in-place 's/\(^GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=\).*/\GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=\"quiet consoleblank=0\"/' /etc/default/grub