# Sreeensaver timeout for 12.04 sever CLI

Tags: command-line, screensaver

I have installed 12.04LTS server edition, no GUI. At some interval, maybe 5 minutes the screen will blank and I have to hit a key to show the screen again.

I have spent hours surfing but cannot find how to change the interval. My question is where do I modify the timeout parameter (through terminal) and where should I have looked for the answer?

There is plenty of advice out there for the GUI version but none I could find for the **CLI** version

Answer (score 1):

Hope this help you
[Link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138918/how-do-i-disable-the-blank-console-screensaver-on-ubuntu-server)

The first answer will help you solve your problems.

Solution

- Open `/etc/default/grub` in your favorite editor; you will need to use `sudo` (for `vi`, `nano`, etc.) or `gksudo` (for `gedit`, etc.).
- Then add `consoleblank=0` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=`, parameter.
- e.g. yours may say:

  ```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash consoleblank=0"
  ```

Then run `sudo update-grub`, and reboot.

Answer (score 0):

From [This link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-disable-screen-blanking-screen-going-blank.html)

`setterm -powersave off -blank 0`

check out `man setterm` for more info.

**Be super careful with this, you can bork your monitor.....**