# how to disable monitor sleep/blanking?

Tags: server, suspend, mode

Ubuntu server system (no X installed) that runs several networking daemons.  It's been headless for years but I recently attached a monitor to it and installed some cli monitoring utilities (glances and pysensors) as this server is also my NAS gateway.

Been on this horrific easter-egg hunt searching for how-to disable the screen-blanking / powersaver mode for the terminal.

I'm hesitant to remove acpi as a package because of unknown/future interdependencies.

Somewhere, there's some obscure config setting that will prevent the monitor from blanking.  I've disabled the sleep option in the monitor's firmware - and, of course a key-press on the kb will awaken the screen...but not sleeping at all is optimal.

thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

did you try the answer to this thread:

[How do I disable the blank console "screensaver" on Ubuntu Server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138918/how-do-i-disable-the-blank-console-screensaver-on-ubuntu-server)

In short it says  to add the parameter `consoleblank=0` to your kernel command-line at boot-time.

Hope that helps.

Comment: the attached article fixed my issue with headless server ubuntu 19.10. Thanks so much. :)